# Как сделать так, чтобы когда наступало какое-то определенное время, то происходило какое-нибудь событие?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

---

```
let clock = document.getElementById("time")

var time = setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  clock.innerHTML = (date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
}, 1000);


if(clock == '18:34:30'){
  alert('hello')
}
```

Comment: Посчитать количество миллисекунд до нужного момента времени и сделать setTimeout, наверное?

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, когда наступало 19:00, появлялось alert-окошко

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обновляете дату каждую секунду, а проверяете только 1 раз при загрузке страницы

```js
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if(clock.textContent == '18:34:30'){
    alert('hello');
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, 500)
```